# Spring security CORS login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cross-domain

I have two different domains for client and server.

My server(actually a REST API) runs with Spring security and below is my code for security configuration

```
@Override  
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
    http  
        .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()  
        .anyRequest().authenticated()  
        .and()  
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();  
}  

@Override  
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {  
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()  
        .withUser("user")  
        .password("{noop}pass") 
        .roles("ADMIN");
}  



@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://clientdoamin.com"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

But I want to login through my client domain and also be able to make future ajax calls without needing to login on every request!

Please help me!!

Comment: You need to use token - JWT
look on this example
https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/ , or , 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/

Answer (score 0):

You can try session-management in spring-security. Please see detailed explanation https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/spring-security.html